# Regular expression for Regex class

Tags: c#, regex

Have to write a Regex that will match following:

```
<a href="../../_asp/link.asp?link=sp1234.htm
```

and

```
<a href="../../_asp/link.asp?link=AL432123.htm
```

Can be only "AL" or "sp" strings after the "=" and any amount of digits before .htm

Will be something like this:

```
 Regex reg = new Regex("<a href=\"../../_asp/link.asp?link=(AL|sp)[0-9]+.htm");
```

Don't know much about regular expressions and have to write this one asap. This substring inside htm file needs to be replaced with another string. Thanks!

Comment: This worked, double backslash before ?  
    Regex reg = new Regex("<a href=\"../../_asp/link.asp\\?link=(AL|sp)[0-9]+\\.htm");

Comment: Why are you trying to parse HTML with regular expressions? That's usually a really bad idea. If at all possible, use a proper HTML parser, like HTML Agility Pack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
new Regex(@"<a href=""\.\./\.\./_asp/link\.asp\?link=(AL|sp)[0-9]+\.htm");
```

Comment: You're escaping `"` incorrectly. In verbatim (`@`) strings, you have to use `""`, not `\"` to represent the character.

Comment: Doh!  Forgot.  Thanks for the catch.  Answer fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First things first - in regex, `.` means any character. You need to escape it with `\.`. `?` is also a special character.

```
Regex reg = new Regex("<a href=\"(\.{2}/){2}_asp/link\.asp\?link=(AL|sp)[0-1]+\.htm");
```

Second, `[0-1]` matches 0 or 1. You want `[0-9]`, or `\d`.

```
Regex reg = new Regex("<a href=\"(\.{2}/){2}_asp/link\.asp\?link=(AL|sp)\d+\.htm");
```

But you should really use an HTML parser rather than a regex to parse HTML.